# merge two dataframe but got more rows than the first dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, merge

I applied merge function to merge two dataframes with two common columns, but the output dataframe df includes more rows than df1. I expected only rows in df1 are in output (not sure if it's always true?). What's the possible reason causing this result?

`df = pd.merge(df_1, df_3,  how='left', left_on=['id','time'], right_on = ['id','time'])`

Comment: Can you share a *reproducible example* of your issue + the matching *expected output* ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pd.merge() with how='left' will create additional rows because most likely there are multiple rows in df_3 that match the same id and time combination in df_1.

if you want to avoid you need to preprocess your data to ensure that there is at most one matching row in df_3 for each id and time combination in df_1. This can be done using methods like drop_duplicates() or groupby()

example:

```
df_3_unique = df_3.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'time'])
df = pd.merge(df_1, df_3_unique, how='left', left_on=['id', 'time'], right_on=['id', 'time'])
```